# Query building over multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to run the following query using Eloquent.

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`, `order_status` WHERE `orders`.`id` = `order_status`.`order_id` AND `orders`.`payment` > 0 AND `order_status`.`status_id` = 1
```

But I'm confused about how to apply the last condition (`order_status.status_id = 1`) on Eloquent since it is on another table. Should I join them or I can apply it via Eloquent relation?

The database schema of the tables:

**ORDERS:**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps('');
            $table->integer('sender_id');
            $table->integer('sender_franchise');
            $table->integer('sender_agent')->nullable();
            $table->integer('recipient_franchise');
            $table->integer('recipient_agent')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->decimal('payment');
            $table->decimal('final_payment');
            $table->string('order_code');
            $table->decimal('extra_charge');
            $table->integer('recipient_id');
            $table->decimal('condition_charge')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('condition_amount')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('condition_charge_recipient')->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->integer('created_by');
            $table->string('receiver_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('receiver_ph')->nullable();
            $table->text('shipping_address')->nullable();
});
```

**ORDER_STATUS:**

```
Schema::create('order_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('order_id');
            $table->integer('status_id');
            $table->integer('created_by');
            $table->timestamps('');
});
```

Comment: show ur database structure of this two tables

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Schema added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
Order::join('order_status', 'orders.id' = 'order_status.order_id')
    ->where('orders.payment', '>', 0)
    ->where('order_status.status_id', '=', '1');
```

Comment: @owlsen Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)

```
DB::table('orders')->join('order_status',function($join){
              $join->on('order_status.order_id','=','orders.id')
                      ->where('order_status.status_id',1)    
})->where('orders.payment','>',0)->get()
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the issue with the solution provided by Saurabh Dhariwal.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by both patterns.

For join try this:

```
Order::join('order_status', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_status.order_id')
->where('orders.payment', '>', 0)
->where('order_status.status_id', 1);
```

For relation try this:

```
Order::with('status')->where('orders.payment', '>', 0)->whereHas('status', function ($q) use ($statusId) {
    $q->where('status_id', $statusId);
});
```

If $statusId is fixed then you can directly specify it as 1.

Also define this relation in your Order model.

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'order_status', 'order_id', 'status_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Nice! The relation is quite the opposite though. Order has many statuses and that was defined already. But I appreciate the solution you provided using relation. It is the one I will apply.